# When does the program terminate before the garbage collection routine run

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am reading the book "Oracle Certified Associate, Java SE 7 Programmer Study Guide".

On the theme of finalize methods there is the sentence: "there is no guarantee that the method will execute as the program may terminate without need for the garbage collection to run".

My question is: Why and when does the program terminate before the garbage collection routine run?

Comment: because it runs whenever it feels like or when there is a shortage of memory.

Comment: This is out of the scope of specification and depends only on implementation of JVM

Comment: If your program is exiting the memory will be released anyway, so garbage collection would be a waste of time and effort.

Comment: Why would the GC run if it doesn't need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this program

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Object() {
        @Override
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("GC");
        }
    };
}
```

Program will terminate but GC will not work. If it would, then it would call finalize() and we would see output on console. GC runs when JVM is low on heap, to make it run add this code

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        byte[] a = new byte[100000000];
    }
```

it creates arrays of large size which quickly fill heap, this makes JVM run GC, actually GC will probably run several times, but JVM can call finalize only once

Answer (score 0):

Program may terminate the following scenario.

All the threads stops irrespective of demons thread.

Will occur System.exit();

Out of memory.

Forcibly shutdown case (kill signal to program from OS).

Answer (score 0):

The only guarantee that you get with regards to garbage collection is that it will have done a best-effort attempt before an `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown.

*Theoretically* you could have a JVM where "best-effort" means "do nothing" because it doesn't have a garbage collector.

In practice the GC often doesn't run if you've got a short-lived JVM instance (for example a simple tool that runs for 1-2 seconds only) or if your process doesn't actually allocate much memory (such as a server process that's just waiting for requests).